# Getting error "failed to send packet header: EOF" while uploading file to sftp server

Tags: go, ssh, sftp

I am facing an issue where in, whenever I try to upload a file to a remote sftp server, I get an error saying **"failed to send packet header: EOF"**. This occurs when I try to perform the uploading step from my own hosted EC2 instance. While locally, everything works fine.

Sftp client is initiated as follow.

```
// Connect to server

var authMethods []ssh.AuthMethod
// Use password authentication if password provided
if pass != "" {
    authMethods = append(authMethods, ssh.Password(pass))
}
config := ssh.ClientConfig{
    User:            user,
    Auth:            authMethods,
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
}

conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", addr, &config)
if err != nil {
    return nil, tearDown, errors.Wrap(err, fmt.Sprintf("failed to connect to %s", addr))
}
tearDown = func() {
    _ = conn.Close()
}

// Create new SFTP client
sc, err := sftp.NewClient(conn)
if err != nil {
    return nil, tearDown, errors.Wrap(err, "Unable to start SFTP subsystem")
}

tearDown = func() {
    fmt.Println("defer is called. closing connection now .... ")
    _ = conn.Close()
    _ = sc.Close()
}
return sc, tearDown, nil
```

And instance of **sc** is attached to a struct and passed around the codebase

Function invoked while uploading file is as follow.

```
    file, err := s.sc.OpenFile(remoteFilePath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC)
    defer func() {
        if file == nil {
            return
        }
        cErr := file.Close()
        if cErr != nil {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("error while closing file %v", cErr))
        }
    }()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("error while opening file %v", err))
        return err
    }
    _, err = file.Write(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("error while writing to file %v", err))
        return err
    }
    return nil
```

Can someone guide me as in where is the error coming from?

Comment: What's the exact error in full, please?  Also have you tested your connection with `sftp -v` to take your program out of the equation?  That will also include debugging information.

Comment: This is the only error that I get. Not sure the exact underlying issue of it. I am able to login and connect to the SFTP using the EC2 instance, its just that whenever I try to do it using the above program, I face this issue.